# Should (not How) I enable CORS in WebApi when using from Android client

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

I have Android client that tries to get Authentication Token using Asp.Net WebApi2. Every time I make a request to get the Token I receive {error: unsupported_grant_type}. My question is could that be somehow related to CORS enabling in my WebAPI project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with CORS.

Have you checked that your request's ContentType is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and pass the data in the body as:

`grant_type=password&username=bob&password=password123`

Comment: My ContentType and had been set as described by you and the grant_type string was set the same, but I'd put the body into a Header instead. 
PS: Can you briefly explain why CORS is not related to this case please?

Comment: CORS is for browsers to perform cross domain requests. Just read the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing